# WIth default host being enabled vsts is throwing the below error when i queue the job

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

Please find the error message below:

> Failed in getBuild with error: Error: tunneling socket could not be
>   established, cause=socket hang up
>
> Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=socket hang up

I am unable to proceed ahead with the default host, I have a private agent configured.

Comment: Can you share the logs in the build agent _diag folder?

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new agent pool, download the agent and configure it with this new pool.

[Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows)